# Cannot set up connection from private subnet to s3 through Gateway Endpoint using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am writing a Terraform configuration for 3 tier architecture on AWS. I want to set up automated daily backups to S3 for my second tier in a private subnet. I am not using a NAT Gateway since I don't want the traffic to be routed to the public Internet hence I want to forward the traffic through a VPC Gateway Endpoint. However, I am unable to achieve that and when I try to issue any aws command from my instance, I get a timeout error:

```bash
aws s3 cp /backup-data/hello.txt s3://mpp-bakcup-bucket/ec2/
Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://ec2.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/"
```

or

```bash
aws ec2 describe-vpc-endpoints
Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://ec2.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/"
```

Troubleshooting done so far:

- I can successfully deploy the architecture on aws using the code below.
- I use a bastion host to ssh into my private instance.
- In my private instance, backup-user and cronjobs are properly set up. However, whenever I try running any aws command like:

```bash
aws --region eu-central-1 s3 ls
aws --region eu-central-1 ec2 describe-vpc-endpoints
```

etc... I receive the following message:

> Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://ec2.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/"

My question is, why can't I establish the connection to s3 from my EC2 instance in the private subnet?

Providing the code below:
Using Terraform, I created:

- vpc, IGW, 3 subnets (1 public & 2 private)
- Route Tables for the Private Subnet:

```
resource "aws_route_table" "private_app_route_table_az1" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  tags = {
    Name = "Private App Route Table az 1"
  }
}
```

- Gateway Endpoint (Attached to the Route Table):

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "s3_endpoint_az1" {
  vpc_id             = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  service_name       = "com.amazonaws.${var.region}.s3"
  vpc_endpoint_type  = "Gateway"

  tags = {
    Name = "my-s3-endpoint az 1"
  }
}

resource "aws_vpc_endpoint_route_table_association" "s3_endpoint_az1_rt_association" {
  route_table_id  = aws_route_table.private_app_route_table_az1.id
  vpc_endpoint_id = aws_vpc_endpoint.s3_endpoint_az1.id
}
```

- Below, I am providing the configuration for the S3 Bucket:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "backup_bucket" {
  bucket = "mpp-bakcup-bucket"
}

resource "aws_s3_object" "ec2_directory" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.backup_bucket.bucket
  key    = "backups/ec2/"
}
```

My idea is to have a backup-user who will run a cronjob daily to copy some directories to S3. I have achieved that by a user data script & a template file:

```
data "template_file" "user_data" {
  template = file("../modules/vpc/user-data.tpl")

  vars = {
    ACCESS_KEY = aws_iam_access_key.backup_user_access_key.id
    SECRET_KEY = aws_iam_access_key.backup_user_access_key.secret
    REGION     = var.region
  }
}

# Assign the rendered user data to a variable from user-data.tpl
locals {
  ec2_user_data_script = data.template_file.user_data.rendered
}
```

Template File:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

apt-get update

mkdir /backup-data
chown -R backup-user:backup-user /backup-data
echo "hello world!" > /backup-data/hello.txt

sudo -u backup-user bash -c 'echo -e "${ACCESS_KEY}\\n${SECRET_KEY}\\n${REGION}\\n\\n" | aws configure'

sudo -u backup-user crontab -l | { cat; echo '0 1 \* \* \* aws s3 cp /backup-data/hello.txt s3://mpp-bakcup-bucket/ec2/'; } | sudo -u backup-user crontab -

service cron restart
```

Also, below I am providing the code for the IAM User creation for backup-user & the policy itself:

- Policy itself:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "s3_access_policy" {
  name        = "s3-access-policy"
  description = "Policy for granting S3 access to backup user"

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::mpp-bakcup-bucket",
        "arn:aws:s3:::mpp-bakcup-bucket/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

- The code for IAM Creation & Policy attachment:

```
resource "aws_iam_user" "backup_user" {
  name = "backup-user"
}

resource "aws_iam_access_key" "backup_user_access_key" {
  user = aws_iam_user.backup_user.name
}

resource "aws_iam_user_policy_attachment" "backup_user_policy_attachment" {
  user       = aws_iam_user.backup_user.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.s3_access_policy.arn
}
```

Comment: Did you verify that your DNS can resolve the S3 endpoint?
what is the result of:
`nslookup s3.amazonaws.com`
and:
`ping s3.amazonaws.com`

Comment: Do you have `enable_dns_support` set to `true` for your VPC?

Comment: Well, if you are going to use e.g., `describe-vpc-endpoints` then your user also needs to have those permissions in the policy. Additionally, `aws s3 ls` is an API call which requires `s3:ListAllMyBuckets` in the permission policy (and possibly `s3:GetBucketLocation`): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-with-s3-actions.html#using-with-s3-actions-related-to-buckets.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the swift response!
Providing answers to the questions in your comments below:
nslookup returns the following value:
Name:   s3.amazonaws.com
Address: 52.216.212.184
...
enable_dns_hostnames = true this is set when configuring the vpc. enable_dns_support  is set to true by default, so I haven't added it.

Regarding the s3 Permissions, I tried giving the user full s3 access:
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "*"
-> Issue persists.

Comment: The error you are referring to is because the user is not allowed to describe the VPC endpoints. Have you added that in the policy?

Comment: I think my initial description of the issue has mislead you. My final goal is that the backup-user is able to perform aws s3 cp command. As a reference, I provided an example that other aws commands (not related to s3) such as aws ec2 describe-vpc-endpoints are not working as well.

Comment: And I'm trying to explain that you cannot perform random API calls without setting the correct permissions for the user, since there is always an implicit Deny, meaning that if you don't allow something, it will be denied by default.